# How to get Context from Kotlin file in Java file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-context

My Application class is developed using Kotlin (I use Dagger2). In a class written in Java, I need to pass Context, but I get a nullpointerexception. How can I get Context?

My Application class:

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)
    }

}
```

My Java Method:

```
public class NotificationUtil {
private static NotificationUtil instance;

    public NotificationUtil() {
    }

    public static synchronized NotificationUtil getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            return new NotificationUtil();
        return instance;
    }

    public void postNotificationSpam(StatusBarNotification sbn, int numberNotify) {
            Context context = new App().getApplicationContext();
            NotificationCompat.Builder ncb;
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call a method in an Activity like this:

```
NotificationUtil.getInstance().postNotificationSpam(lstNotify.get(0).barNotification, lstNotify.size());
```

My error code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
        at com.package.cleanapp.service.NotificationUtil.postNotificationSpam(NotificationUtil.java:204)
```

Comment: where is the method located in?In an activity or what

Comment: This is a public NotificationUtil class

Answer (score 1):

You are using new App().getApplicationContext();.Do not use this.Because your app is opened,but not initialized.Instead you can use `this`.

Comment: I can't use this, it needs to be in an Activity to do this.

Comment: then where is the method located

Comment: Required type:
Context
Provided:
NotificationUtil

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by passing the context through the constructor

```
public void postNotificationSpam(Context context, StatusBarNotification sbn, int numberNotify) {
            NotificationCompat.Builder ncb;
            NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }
```

In Activity:

```
NotificationUtil.getInstance().postNotificationSpam(this, lstNotify.get(0).barNotification, lstNotify.size());
```

Comment: If you're already using dagger, you can consider converting this to an application scoped singleton and injecting the application context instead. There's no need to maintain your own instance or to pass in context that way

Comment: Look at my question, no matter how I try to embed the context, I always get a null pointer exception.